# adding Lines to Xml file At Specific location

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file "message.xml" in which messages are written like :-

< messages>
< message id="1" name="last" text="welcome All"/>
-..

-..

-..

< message id="10" name="first" text="welcome"/>
< /message>

Now i have to add message lines after last message each time through my program,
the problem is how to find the last line or place where i have to add the lines (like just before< /message> tag) ??

Comment: How are you reading the file? What objects are you using?

Comment: It is XML, treat it as such. Use an XML parser, don't try to do string manipulation on it.

Comment: iam using streamReader and reading it into string format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345449.aspx) to manipulate XML files:

```
XDocument
    .Load("test.xml")
    .Root
    .Add(
        new XElement(
            "message", 
            new XAttribute("id", "123"),
            new XAttribute("name", "foo"),
            new XAttribute("text", "bar")
        )
    )
    .Save("test.xml");
```

Comment: there is a problem ..I am getting these messages through UI. user will enter there their messages . some message may contain 3 or some  may contain 5 attributes and also not in same order. like:-                 <message text="hi" severity=4 id="20"/> then how to handle that???

Answer (score 0):

Load the file into an XmlDocument (or an XDocumnent). Then you can add new message elements to the root messages element. Then resave it. No need to do text-file editing.